# Get mean of numbers in character string before and after comma

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, average, mean

I have a data frame (df) with character columns. Each index consist of a string of numbers, separated by a comma. See reproducible example:

```
a<-c("1,2", "6,8", "6,9")
b<-c("4,7","9,3","5,5")
c<-c("2,1","5,4","8,9")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))
```

I want to calculate row mean separately for the numbers before the comma and the numbers after the comma.  Preferably with tidyverse/dplyr. The output would look like this:

```
    a   b   c mean1 mean2
  1,2 4,7 2,1  2.33  3.33
  6,8 9,3 5,4  6.67  5.00
  6,9 5,5 8,9  6.00  7.67
```

So the first index in mean1 is the average of the numbers before the commas in the first row ((1+4+2)/3). And the first index in mean2 is the average of the numbers after the commas in the first row ((2+7+1)/3).

I have looked at another post suggesting using library(splitstackshape) and the cSplit command, but I cannot get it to work.

```
df <- df %>% cSplit(c("a","b","c"), direction = "wide") %>%
  summarise(mean = rowMeans(c("a","b","c")))
```

I have also tried by splitting columns by comma and converting them to wide and all sorts of other things. If it can be solved this way, it will definitely be the easiest way. And if you can come up with a solution that does not involve the column names, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making use of `dplyr` this could be achieved like so:

1. Make new cols with the value `before` and `after` the comma
2. Compute the means of these cols using `rowwise()` and `c_across()`
3. get rid of the auxilliary cols

```r
a<-c("1,2", "6,8", "6,9")
b<-c("4,7","9,3","5,5")
c<-c("2,1","5,4","8,9")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(a:c, list(
    before = ~ as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(., "^\\d+")),
    after = ~ as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(., "\\d+$"))), .names = "{.col}_{.fn}")) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(mean1 = mean(c_across(ends_with("before"))),
         mean2 = mean(c_across(ends_with("after")))) %>% 
  select(-ends_with("before"), -ends_with("after"))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   a     b     c     mean1 mean2
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 1,2   4,7   2,1    2.33  3.33
#> 2 6,8   9,3   5,4    6.67  5   
#> 3 6,9   5,5   8,9    6.33  7.67
```

Comment: hmm I get an error:
```
Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x glue cannot interpolate functions into strings.
* object '.col' is a function.
```
In another thread it was suggested that I remove the "." before col (so that it becomes "{col}_{.fn}"). But then I ge
```
Error: unexpected ',' in "    before = ~ as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(., "^\\d+")),"
>     
Error: unexpected ')' in "    after = ~ as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(., "\\d+$")))"
>   
Error in UseMethod("rowwise") : 
```
Can you figure out what this means?

Comment: Hi Skarup. Hard to tell. Just checked my code again. Works fine on my machine using dplyr 1.0.2 and glue 1.4.3 and R 4.0.2. Also using `{col}` works fine. Additonally I a quick google search but except for the SO post where the issue was solved using `col` I found no reference on the specific error.

Comment: Hi again. By also moving the "." before ".fn" the issue was solved! Thank you so much for helping me with this :)

Comment: Actually I have one more question. Any idea why str_extract converts negative numbers to NA? :)

Comment: Aw. Sorry. Always the negative numbers. Use `before = ~ as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(., "^-?\\d+"))`. The `-?` will take account of an optional minus sign.